# Context.SubmitChanges() not updating despite having a PK

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having an issue with the SubmitChanges function provided by the linq to DB implementation in C#. When I run the command, nothing throws an error but the record never gets updated. I have looked up the issue almost everyone says that it is in issue with the table nothing a primary key. However my table has a primary key assigned to it and yet SubmitChanges does not happen. To give you an overview of what I am executing, I here is a sample:

```
public void setApproval(string approvalCode, int ID)
{
    using (DatabaseDataContext context = new DatabaseDataContext(DBConnection().getConnectionString()))
    {
        myRecord con = getRecord(ID); //Gets the record succesfully, PK field in tact
        con.ApprovalStatus = approvalCode;

        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

As commented above, the record is successfully obtained with all the data in tact, including the PK field used to identify it. The database connection user is given the rights to update the table, though here I would expect it to break and complain.

Any ideas? Please let me know if I have not provided enough information. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might be caused by the getRecord method not using the same context object.

Comment: Did you check in the Model Designer that the primary key was defined on the object there? I don't know why it wouldn't be there, but I've had some weirdness using EF with some existing databases that weren't built real well.

Comment: I don't see how your code could work.  You're calling SubmitChanges on the context, but you're never changing anything in that context.  Your getRecrod method does not use the context you created, and likely uses a different context.  SaveChanges would need to be called on THAT context.

Comment: Wonderful, this works! Sorry guys, I haven't gotten much sleep in the last 48 hours. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where does getRecord(ID) get its context to return a record?  It is not getting passed to the method, so I assume it is using a different context.   SubmitChanges() would only see changes for the current context, not the context that getRecord(ID) used.

Answer (score 5):

You should get the object through context

```
public void setApproval(string approvalCode, int ID)
{
    using (DatabaseDataContext context = new DatabaseDataContext(DBConnection().getConnectionString()))
    {
        myRecord con = context.TableName.First(item => item.ID == ID); //Gets the record succesfully, PK field in tact
        con.ApprovalStatus = approvalCode;

        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

When you get the object via Context, it keep track of changes you make and then it save those changes on SubmitChanges

Comment: I did this a little bit differently where I passed in the context into the retrieving function. That way the context is consistent and I can still make use of that function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking to see if the data was updated with code or with an independent DB tool?

If in code, your read code is as suspect as the write code:
I was having similar issues when two applications with no common API were communicating through a database.  The context is not a reflection of what is in the DB right now, and no amount of telling it to refresh is going to entirely fix the problem.  If you need to inspect the database for something entered by another program or thread, you have to create a new database context object to inspect the database.  The old database context object may still have the old data from before your most recent update.

Your `getRecord` function needs to create a new context or take the current context that you just edited as a parameter.  If it uses a static or class level context it will not have the latest data.